# notepad++ folding based on whitespace depth

Tags: notepad++, folding

I'm looking for a way to fold plaintext by whitespace depth. I would prefer for a notepad++ solution, but if it can only be done in another editor I could deal with that. For example

```
Header is arbitrary text
 Child is arbitrary text
 Another arbitrary child
  This one has a child of its own
Another arbitrary header
 And its child
```

Folding line 1 should hide lines 2-4, folding line 3 should hide line 4, and folding line 5 should hide line 6. I've tried a user defined language, but haven't been able to get it to fold without specific block start and end delimiters.

Comment: Set the language to Python, that seems to work. Perhaps you could copy the language definition and remove the syntax highlighting too.

Comment: That is similar to what I'm currently doing. Since (AFAIK) built in languages can't be copied and modified, I just use the python lexer with all the syntax highlighting disabled. The only problem with this is that I also edit actual python code sometimes, and I would like the highlighting to be on then.

Comment: So I see.. Perhaps you could mess around with the style configurator and set up some relatively easy way to switch highlighting on and off.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Notepad++, change the language > p > python.
It will create automatically the folding based on space.

Comment: I just saw that it was the same answer from @Blorgbeard.

Comment: Still, added value from this being an answer instead of a comment. Something better to upvote.